# authenticate API endpoint with .Net Classic MVC 5 Web App

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a .Net Classic web app. We are revamping the whole thing, and the frontend is being stripped out and moved to another framework. Some elements of this app will remain, to be ported to .NET Core at a later date.

As such, I need to add a few API endpoints to the app. I'd rather leave the working MSAL auth in the app so that I can maybe have some frontend debugging tools in the future. But I'd like the API endpoints to use (ideally) OAuth.

Can someone point me at some documentation for my auth scenario? The documentation is years old at this point so I'm having trouble digging something up for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Because our use case involved two internal services sending messages to eachother, we opted to sign each message with Hmac. Between message signing, https, and separate IP whitelisting, we decided this was sufficient security for our use case.

Hmac roughly works like this:

Create a message signature on the transmitting end;

- Add a Guid(nonce), timestamp, and the message content to signature raw data.
- Instantiate Hmac using a pre shared secret key.
- Generate a hash that represents your signature

Transmit the signature, Guid, and Timestamp in the authorization header.

Create a hash on the receiving end from the same data, and compare the hash you've made with the hash you received;

- Generate the hash using the same steps as above, but this time, compare that hash to the signature in the authorization header. If the signature is exactly the same, your message is genuine.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to implement OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308227(v=vs.113)

Comment: Is there a way to use a different auth provider? Like one of the microsoft auth endpoints?

Comment: This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).